# Failing to install Orange using miniconda or/and anaconda (SOLVED TEMPORARILY)

Tags: anaconda, miniconda, orange

SOLVED TEMPORARILY, TEMP SOLUTION AT BOTTUM
Trying to install Orange for a data science class at my school. I had a previous version at least 6 months ago and removed it after not using it. Trying to reinstall it I get the following:

```
> Creating an new conda env in "C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Orange"
Output folder: C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Temp\nsc7595.tmp\Orange-installer-data\conda-pkgs
Extract: _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.tar.bz2
Extract: anyqt-0.0.13-pyh6c4a22f_0.tar.bz2
Extract: baycomp-1.0.2-py_1.tar.bz2
Extract: blas-2.109-openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: blas-devel-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: bottleneck-1.3.2-py38h347fdf6_3.tar.bz2
Extract: brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h294d835_1001.tar.bz2
Extract: ca-certificates-2021.5.30-h5b45459_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cachecontrol-0.12.6-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: catboost-0.26-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: certifi-2021.5.30-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cffi-1.14.5-py38hd8c33c5_0.tar.bz2
Extract: chardet-4.0.0-py38haa244fe_1.tar.bz2
Extract: commonmark-0.9.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: conda-spec.txt
Extract: cryptography-3.4.7-py38hd7da0ea_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cycler-0.10.0-py_2.tar.bz2
Extract: decorator-5.0.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: dictdiffer-0.8.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: docutils-0.17.1-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py_1001.tar.bz2
Extract: freetype-2.10.4-h546665d_1.tar.bz2
Extract: future-0.18.2-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: h11-0.12.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: h2-4.0.0-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: hpack-4.0.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: httpcore-0.12.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: httpx-0.16.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: hyperframe-6.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: icu-68.1-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: idna-2.10-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: importlib-metadata-4.5.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: importlib_metadata-4.5.0-hd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: install.bat
Extract: jbig-2.1-h8d14728_2003.tar.bz2
Extract: jdcal-1.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: joblib-1.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: jpeg-9d-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: keyring-23.0.1-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: keyrings.alt-4.0.2-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: kiwisolver-1.3.1-py38hbd9d945_1.tar.bz2
Extract: lcms2-2.12-h2a16943_0.tar.bz2
Extract: lerc-2.2.1-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: libblas-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libcblas-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libclang-11.1.0-default_h5c34c98_1.tar.bz2
Extract: libdeflate-1.7-h8ffe710_5.tar.bz2
Extract: libflang-5.0.0-h6538335_20180525.tar.bz2
Extract: liblapack-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: liblapacke-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libopenblas-0.3.15-pthreads_hc469a61_0.tar.bz2
Extract: libpng-1.6.37-h1d00b33_2.tar.bz2
Extract: libtiff-4.3.0-h0c97f57_1.tar.bz2
Extract: libxgboost-1.4.0-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: llvm-meta-5.0.0-0.tar.bz2
Extract: lockfile-0.12.2-py_1.tar.bz2
Extract: lz4-c-1.9.3-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2.tar.bz2
Extract: matplotlib-base-3.4.2-py38heae8d8c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: msgpack-python-1.0.2-py38hbd9d945_1.tar.bz2
Extract: msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1.tar.bz2
Extract: networkx-2.5-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: numpy-1.19.5-py38h0cc643e_1.tar.bz2
Extract: olefile-0.46-pyh9f0ad1d_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openblas-0.3.15-pthreads_h543f93c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: openjpeg-2.4.0-hb211442_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openmp-5.0.0-vc14_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openpyxl-3.0.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: openssl-1.1.1k-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: opentsne-0.6.0-py38h2f20550_1.tar.bz2
Extract: orange-canvas-core-0.1.21-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: orange-widget-base-4.13.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: orange3-3.29.3-py38h60cbd38_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pandas-1.2.4-py38h60cbd38_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pillow-8.2.0-py38h9273828_1.tar.bz2
Extract: pip-21.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: py-xgboost-1.4.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pycparser-2.20-pyh9f0ad1d_2.tar.bz2
Extract: pyopenssl-20.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyparsing-2.4.7-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt-5.12.3-py38haa244fe_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt-impl-5.12.3-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt5-sip-4.19.18-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtchart-5.12-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtgraph-0.12.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtwebengine-5.12.1-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pysocks-1.7.1-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: python-3.8.8-h7840368_0_cpython.tar.bz2
Extract: python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: python-louvain-0.15-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: python_abi-3.8-1_cp38.tar.bz2
Extract: pytz-2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py38haa244fe_1003.tar.bz2
Extract: pyyaml-5.4.1-py38h294d835_0.tar.bz2
Extract: qasync-0.16.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4.tar.bz2
Extract: requests-2.25.1-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: rfc3986-1.5.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: scikit-learn-0.23.2-py38ha09990b_3.tar.bz2
Extract: scipy-1.5.3-py38h5f893b4_0.tar.bz2
Extract: serverfiles-0.3.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: setuptools-49.6.0-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: sitecustomize.py
Extract: six-1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sniffio-1.2.0-py38haa244fe_1.tar.bz2
Extract: sqlite-3.35.5-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: threadpoolctl-2.1.0-pyh5ca1d4c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: tk-8.6.10-h8ffe710_1.tar.bz2
Extract: tornado-6.1-py38h294d835_1.tar.bz2
Extract: typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-pyha770c72_0.tar.bz2
Extract: urllib3-1.26.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: vc-14.2-hb210afc_4.tar.bz2
Extract: vs2015_runtime-14.28.29325-h5e1d092_4.tar.bz2
Extract: wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py38haa244fe_2.tar.bz2
Extract: wincertstore-0.2-py38haa244fe_1006.tar.bz2
Extract: xgboost-1.4.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: xlrd-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_3.tar.bz2
Extract: xlsxwriter-1.4.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_1.tar.bz2
Extract: yaml-0.2.5-he774522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: zipp-3.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_1010.tar.bz2
Extract: zstd-1.5.0-h6255e5f_0.tar.bz2
Output folder: C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Temp\nsc7595.tmp\Orange-installer-data\conda-pkgs
Installing packages (this might take a while)
Executing: cmd.exe /c install.bat "C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Orange" "C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
"conda" command exited with 1. Cannot continue.
```

After reading several helps threads online like [here](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/4013),
output after conda.exe info:

```
> active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\tujo1\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.4=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\tujo1\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\tujo1\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.9.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

After that I then tried conda clean --all and rerunning orange installation this is the output:

```
> Creating an new conda env in "C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Orange"
Output folder: C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Temp\nsi5613.tmp\Orange-installer-data\conda-pkgs
Extract: _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.tar.bz2
Extract: anyqt-0.0.13-pyh6c4a22f_0.tar.bz2
Extract: baycomp-1.0.2-py_1.tar.bz2
Extract: blas-2.109-openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: blas-devel-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: bottleneck-1.3.2-py38h347fdf6_3.tar.bz2
Extract: brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h294d835_1001.tar.bz2
Extract: ca-certificates-2021.5.30-h5b45459_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cachecontrol-0.12.6-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: catboost-0.26-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: certifi-2021.5.30-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cffi-1.14.5-py38hd8c33c5_0.tar.bz2
Extract: chardet-4.0.0-py38haa244fe_1.tar.bz2
Extract: commonmark-0.9.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: conda-spec.txt
Extract: cryptography-3.4.7-py38hd7da0ea_0.tar.bz2
Extract: cycler-0.10.0-py_2.tar.bz2
Extract: decorator-5.0.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: dictdiffer-0.8.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: docutils-0.17.1-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py_1001.tar.bz2
Extract: freetype-2.10.4-h546665d_1.tar.bz2
Extract: future-0.18.2-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: h11-0.12.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: h2-4.0.0-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: hpack-4.0.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: httpcore-0.12.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: httpx-0.16.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: hyperframe-6.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: icu-68.1-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: idna-2.10-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: importlib-metadata-4.5.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: importlib_metadata-4.5.0-hd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: install.bat
Extract: jbig-2.1-h8d14728_2003.tar.bz2
Extract: jdcal-1.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: joblib-1.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: jpeg-9d-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: keyring-23.0.1-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: keyrings.alt-4.0.2-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: kiwisolver-1.3.1-py38hbd9d945_1.tar.bz2
Extract: lcms2-2.12-h2a16943_0.tar.bz2
Extract: lerc-2.2.1-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: libblas-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libcblas-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libclang-11.1.0-default_h5c34c98_1.tar.bz2
Extract: libdeflate-1.7-h8ffe710_5.tar.bz2
Extract: libflang-5.0.0-h6538335_20180525.tar.bz2
Extract: liblapack-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: liblapacke-3.9.0-9_openblas.tar.bz2
Extract: libopenblas-0.3.15-pthreads_hc469a61_0.tar.bz2
Extract: libpng-1.6.37-h1d00b33_2.tar.bz2
Extract: libtiff-4.3.0-h0c97f57_1.tar.bz2
Extract: libxgboost-1.4.0-h0e60522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: llvm-meta-5.0.0-0.tar.bz2
Extract: lockfile-0.12.2-py_1.tar.bz2
Extract: lz4-c-1.9.3-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2.tar.bz2
Extract: m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2.tar.bz2
Extract: matplotlib-base-3.4.2-py38heae8d8c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: msgpack-python-1.0.2-py38hbd9d945_1.tar.bz2
Extract: msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1.tar.bz2
Extract: networkx-2.5-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: numpy-1.19.5-py38h0cc643e_1.tar.bz2
Extract: olefile-0.46-pyh9f0ad1d_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openblas-0.3.15-pthreads_h543f93c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: openjpeg-2.4.0-hb211442_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openmp-5.0.0-vc14_1.tar.bz2
Extract: openpyxl-3.0.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: openssl-1.1.1k-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: opentsne-0.6.0-py38h2f20550_1.tar.bz2
Extract: orange-canvas-core-0.1.21-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: orange-widget-base-4.13.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: orange3-3.29.3-py38h60cbd38_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pandas-1.2.4-py38h60cbd38_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pillow-8.2.0-py38h9273828_1.tar.bz2
Extract: pip-21.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: py-xgboost-1.4.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pycparser-2.20-pyh9f0ad1d_2.tar.bz2
Extract: pyopenssl-20.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyparsing-2.4.7-pyh9f0ad1d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt-5.12.3-py38haa244fe_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt-impl-5.12.3-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqt5-sip-4.19.18-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtchart-5.12-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtgraph-0.12.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pyqtwebengine-5.12.1-py38h885f38d_7.tar.bz2
Extract: pysocks-1.7.1-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: python-3.8.8-h7840368_0_cpython.tar.bz2
Extract: python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: python-louvain-0.15-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: python_abi-3.8-1_cp38.tar.bz2
Extract: pytz-2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py38haa244fe_1003.tar.bz2
Extract: pyyaml-5.4.1-py38h294d835_0.tar.bz2
Extract: qasync-0.16.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4.tar.bz2
Extract: requests-2.25.1-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: rfc3986-1.5.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: scikit-learn-0.23.2-py38ha09990b_3.tar.bz2
Extract: scipy-1.5.3-py38h5f893b4_0.tar.bz2
Extract: serverfiles-0.3.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Extract: setuptools-49.6.0-py38haa244fe_3.tar.bz2
Extract: sitecustomize.py
Extract: six-1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0.tar.bz2
Extract: sniffio-1.2.0-py38haa244fe_1.tar.bz2
Extract: sqlite-3.35.5-h8ffe710_0.tar.bz2
Extract: threadpoolctl-2.1.0-pyh5ca1d4c_0.tar.bz2
Extract: tk-8.6.10-h8ffe710_1.tar.bz2
Extract: tornado-6.1-py38h294d835_1.tar.bz2
Extract: typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-pyha770c72_0.tar.bz2
Extract: urllib3-1.26.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: vc-14.2-hb210afc_4.tar.bz2
Extract: vs2015_runtime-14.28.29325-h5e1d092_4.tar.bz2
Extract: wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2
Extract: win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py38haa244fe_2.tar.bz2
Extract: wincertstore-0.2-py38haa244fe_1006.tar.bz2
Extract: xgboost-1.4.0-py38haa244fe_0.tar.bz2
Extract: xlrd-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_3.tar.bz2
Extract: xlsxwriter-1.4.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_1.tar.bz2
Extract: yaml-0.2.5-he774522_0.tar.bz2
Extract: zipp-3.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
Extract: zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_1010.tar.bz2
Extract: zstd-1.5.0-h6255e5f_0.tar.bz2
Output folder: C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Temp\nsi5613.tmp\Orange-installer-data\conda-pkgs
Installing packages (this might take a while)
Executing: cmd.exe /c install.bat "C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Orange" "C:\Users\tujo1\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
"conda" command exited with 1. Cannot continue.
```

I have tried fresh installs of both anaconda and miniconda as well as previous versions of orange. I have also tried installing orange and letting the orange installed install miniconda and that does not work eiter. I have looked all over stack and google and have tried everything that I have saw and I still can't get orange to install.

Using windows 10
64 bit installers

Creating a new user account on the pc and installing orange on that account worked. Still need to figure out why the environment is messed up on the main account.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts like this sometimes pop up if there were previously installed Anaconda/Miniconda environments.

If you haven't yet, you may try two options:

1. Make a new user account on the system and try installing there. Maybe a clean user would help resolve the conflicting environment. If this works, then uninstalling/manually cleaning all Anaconda/Miniconda remnants from your system would likely make the original user work too.
2. Perhaps try the "Portable Orange". It is a zip archive you just unzip and run directly. See here: https://orangedatamining.com/download/#windows

Please report if any of these worked. I am one of Orange's developers. We are aware that Windows installation can sometimes fail, but it is surprisingly hard to get the installers working properly on all systems.

Comment: Making a new user account and installing it there works. I will work on uninstalling and cleaning environment. Portable orange did not work, the shortcut would not open

Comment: Apart from cleaning the conda environments try deleting the C:\Users\tujo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Orange folder. I have no idea what else could go wrong. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I ended up doing a fresh install of windows and wiping everything.